# Java cannot find symbol when implementing Android Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm writing my first android application and having some trouble. Consider the following code:

```java
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView textView;
    textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    //textView.setText("TEST");
    setContentView(textView);
}
```

This code compiles as long as the `setText` line stays commented. If i uncomment it, i get the following error: `cannot find symbol: variable textView`

Am i doing something obviously wrong here? I'm new to android and it's been years since I wrote any java (I write a lot more C and my instincts tend to lead me astray...)

Edit:

This function is a simplification of the example code here:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Is this example wrong? It doesn't look like i should have to create such a simple view in the manifest, this looks like a java linker error to me? I appreciate your responses, but I'm still having trouble understanding what's wrong.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?  If so, try cleaning and recompiling.  What you are doing looks OK.  The fact that you can set the text size but not the text is most odd.  BTW, +1 to cancel the stupid downvote.

Comment: The example can never be wrong. It's just another way of doing things. Kindly have a look at the EDIT section of my answer.

Comment: I'm building with `ant clean debug`. It is very wierd that i can change the size but not the text.

Comment: Delete the out and gen directories and try again.

Comment: No dice...still the same error after deleting those directories :( This kind of feels like a CLASSPATH issue, but it's weird that i can call setTextSize but not setText.

Comment: This seems like a case of bad error-reporting on the compiler. I just deleted a few lines and re-typed them, and now it compiles. There's some kind of error here, but it's a small typo or something (maybe whitespace? java isn't whitespace sensitive like python, is it?)

Comment: Nope, not whitespace sensitive.  Glad to hear it's fixed though.  Weird things happen every so often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. setContentView(tv) first then set text to textview. You can do as below.

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   TextView tv= new TextView(this);
   setContentView(tv);
   tv.setText("hello");
    }
   }
   ```
2. In your main.xml

   ```
   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello" />
   ```

In your activity

```
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

I would suggest you take the second part. Your xml is used to define UI which is seperate from your logic defined in MainActivity.java file. Any changes you make to the UI, you need need not make changes to your java file. In your xml file you can set text view size. You need not change the logic in .java file.

Similarly changes you make to .java file, not required to make changes in the xml.

Comment: +1 for the explanation you provided as to why the logic and the UI should be kept separate.

Answer (score 2):

A few places where you are going wrong :

-you should call `setContentView()` before trying to reference any view

-`setContentView()` takes the name of the XML file which contains your layout

-you need to make a reference to the TextView in your layout in the JAva code by using `findViewById`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.name_of_your_xml_file_which_has_the_layout);
    TextView textView;
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_of_the_textView_as_given_in_your_layout.xml);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText("TEST");
}
```

**EDIT :**
The code given [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#CreateActivity) creates a TextView dynamically and the method that my answer contains uses a static layout and just references the textView in the java code. This is the standard way to do it as it gets really difficult to implement dynamic layouts once things get complicated. Now, things seem easy as there is only one TextView. But with more UI elements, you are just inviting more trouble *(in my opinion)*. I would suggest you to follow the static layout method, especially since you are beginning with Android.

Comment: I was under the impression that i didn't need the view defined in a layout if it was so simple...

Comment: Well, you can have a blank layout and you would still need to do it!

Comment: What the OP is trying to do is perfectly legal, and not using setContentView() would not cause a compiler error.  There is something else going on here.

Comment: @swayam No you don't.  You do not have to use setContentView.

Comment: @Simon : Yes, I just realised that he is creating the layout dynamically. Maybe he should just clean his project.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a text view in your layout file like :

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
```

And then find it inside your code and then assign it to the variable:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
// Now you can do whatever you want with this textview
```

Comment: What the OP is trying to do is perfectly legal, and not using setContentView() would not cause a compiler error.  There is something else going on here.